# How to get all values from guava LoadingCache without passing any keys

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Guava LoadingCache to cache some of the results. Using load method I fetch results from other source and put into cache using '`put(key,value)`'.
Now the problem I am trying to solve is: I want to get all the available results in that cache with out passing any keys. Because I am interested in taking all the values presented in the cache at that time regardless of any specific keys.

`getall(Iterable<?> keys)` or `getAllPresent(Iterable<?> keys)` methods are there but those are expecting the keys to be passed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`(Loading)Cache#asMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap--) view and operate on returned `ConcurrentMap`. There's nice description on Guava [wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#asmap):

> You can view any `Cache` as a `ConcurrentMap` using its `asMap` view, but
>   how the `asMap` view interacts with the `Cache` requires some explanation.
>
> - `cache.asMap()` contains all entries that are currently loaded in the
>     cache. So, for example, `cache.asMap().keySet()` contains all the
>     currently loaded keys.

Comment: Can we check for isempty() or something similar on LoadingCache? before accessing its elements.

Comment: `LoadingCache`, as name tells you, loads (computes) the value if its missing or already evicted, so there's no need to check anything before accessing (if you really need to distinguish between empty *value*, you can always use [`Cache#getIfPresent(K)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#getIfPresent-java.lang.Object-).