# Cache.asMap().put() or Cache.put()

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Google-guava-cache. Defined it as:

```
Cache<String, String> myCache= CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100).build();
```

When I do the map operation such as get/put using:

```
  myCache.asMap().put("someString", "someString");
  String someValueFromCache = myCache.asMap().get("someString");
```

I want to know will there be any optimization or any kind of difference if I use it according to the following manner i.e. without using it as map:

```
  myCache.put("someString", "someString");
  String someValueFromCache = myCache.get("someString");
```

Comment: They're precisely equivalent, so it won't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the guava cache docs: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#inserted-directly

> Values may be inserted into the cache directly with cache.put(key,
>   value). This overwrites any previous entry in the cache for the
>   specified key. Changes can also be made to a cache using any of the
>   ConcurrentMap methods exposed by the Cache.asMap() view. Note that no
>   method on the asMap view will ever cause entries to be automatically
>   loaded into the cache. Further, the atomic operations on that view
>   operate outside the scope of automatic cache loading, so Cache.get(K,
>   Callable) should always be preferred over Cache.asMap().putIfAbsent
>   in caches which load values using either CacheLoader or Callable.

Don't think you should be using the `asMap()` view for modifying the cache.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @rdas answer, couple notes:

1. If you don't use `LoadingCache` (as in your example), there's really no difference between the two (well, using `.asMap()` is more cluttered), and sometimes you want / have to use `(Concurrent)Map` interface for compatibility, in which case using `.asMap()` is perfectly fine.
2. If you want to access / iterate over all keys / values, `Cache` interface doesn't offer such methods, but `Map` does -- see [my other answer on "How to get all values from Guava `LoadingCache` without passing any keys"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200531/how-to-get-all-values-from-guava-loadingcache-without-passing-any-keys).
3. There's also other difference (it's in documentation actually, but I learned it the hard way): modifying `Cache` by its `.asMap()` view doesn't update [`CacheStats`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheStats.html), if you have them enabled via [`CacheBuilder#recordStats()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#recordStats--).